# element strings length html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm following https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercises.php and got stuck on exercise 5:

> 5. Write a JavaScript program to rotate the string 'w3resource' in the right direction. This is done by periodically removing one letter from the string end and attaching it to the front.

my first thought was create a variable and using queryselector to get my content inside my H1, now im looking for a way to change that string. I know in JS, strings are immutable, so my idea is based on using a different variable to do that, till there my thought was fine, but im stucked in how i can get a required index on a text inside my H1 element and it is just yielding me wrong lenght, i dont know why. I've already read a lot JS contents on MDN website, but couldnt find any that might help me.

```js
let MyString = document.querySelector(".rotate_h1_content");

let output = document.querySelector(".output");

output.textContent = MyString.childNodes[0].length;
```

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}

h1{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

}
.rotate_h1_content, .rotate_content{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.outer_content{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="Training">
        <meta name="author" content="Vitor Mota">
        <title>Training</title><!--Practice-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                       <!--Estou colocando em ingles, mas vou traduzindo nos comentarios-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFile2.css">
        <script src="JsExc2.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="outer_content">
            <div class="rotate_content">
                <h1 class="rotate_h1_content">
                   Any string
                </h1>
                <h2 class="output">
                   
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

i tried use child nodes and lenght to see if my string has the right lenght, but just yield that akward 47 number, and my first character is on 20 index, can someone help me? i though that it might be the padding and margin giving those extra charaters, but are not

Comment: What does "rotating a string" mean? Do you mean you need to rotate an HTML element, or how to change the content of an HTML element? Because neither of those "change strings", the first would be a CSS task, the second is simply a matter of _replacing_ one string with another. Right now you're doing the latter, setting the element's text to the length of the string inside your `h1`. Also, please remember to only show off the problem you're asking about: there's way more CSS in your snippet than there needs to be, and your HTML contains a bunch of `<head>` content that is entirely unnecessary

Comment: i need to rotate a string(any) on html 

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercises.php

exercise 5: Write a JavaScript program to rotate the string 'w3resource' in the right direction. This is done by periodically removing one letter from the string end and attaching it to the front.......

So i was looking for a way to treating a string, inside a html element, as simple as any other language, but at first, it is giving me the wrong lenght.

Comment: Then please [edit] your post to say that, and include that description in your post, because that is not a normal use of the word rotate (that's "rolling" or even "scrolling" a string, not "rotating" a string). The exercise tells you what you're supposed to do: take a string, split it into "the last letter" and "everything before the last letter", and then create a new string with those two parts.

Comment: Im sorry, i was using the website  exercise description.

Comment: Search the web and/or stackoverflow for how to split a string using JavaScript (should be fairly easy to find, it's a built-in function). Reading through a few posts/pages about how to do that and seeing the examples they show should then let you figure out how to do this exercise just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with string operations:

```js
let p = document.getElementById("something");
current = p.innerText;
setInterval(function() {
    p.innerText = current = current.substring(1) + current[0];
}, 200);
```

```html
<p id="something">Any string</p>
```

Comment: you didnt had to use trim() here to avoid the white spaces before the string, why ?

Comment: @Sung-99 because I didn't have white characters before and after Any string in my p. If this answer solved the problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Sung-99 you can wrap trim() at the first initialization of current around p.innerText if you might have whitespaces that you do not want.

Comment: NOW i got it, i just add enter after my div, and aft my h1 declaration, so thats why it has 47 charaters, thanks.

Comment: im trying to understand your answer, ok it is right, but can you explain why have  you to assign two times ?

Comment: @Sung-99 sure. `innerText` is a very special thing in Javascript, because when you change its value, it is refreshing the structure of your webpage. When your string ends with a space, assigning it to `innerText` may trim it down as unnecessary whitespace (which happened when I tried it) and hence it's better to have a string that does not convert back & forth HTML structure and from which your intended whitespaces are not trimmed unless you want it to be trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

The "length" is also counting all of the spaces before the word "Any".

If you `trim()` off the spaces, you will get the correct number.

Perhaps in this instance you should not format that specific div in your code - it will be easier to work with it like this:

```
<h1 class="rotate_h1_content">Any string</h1>
```

```js
let MyString = document.querySelector(".rotate_h1_content");

let output = document.querySelector(".output");

output.textContent += MyString.textContent.trim().length;
```

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}

h1{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

}
.rotate_h1_content, .rotate_content{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.outer_content{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="Training">
        <meta name="author" content="Vitor Mota">
        <title>Training</title><!--Practice-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                       <!--Estou colocando em ingles, mas vou traduzindo nos comentarios-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFile2.css">
        <script src="JsExc2.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="outer_content">
            <div class="rotate_content">
                <h1 class="rotate_h1_content">
                   Any string
                </h1>
                <h2 class="output">
                   
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there will be always others white space before a nactual text in a html element ?

Comment: No, you added those spaces when you structured your HTML as you did - the javascript is counting all the spaces from the margin in your HTML. Note that the web page will only display one space character (that is how HTML works) but javascript will capture all ~ 40 spaces. So you can either use `.trim()` as I did when you read the textContent in javascript, or you can remove any extra spaces from the HTML, as suggested in my answer.